# How to prevent bleach from escaping > (blockquote) tag used in Markdown

Tags: python, html, django, markdown, sanitization

I'm using bleach to sanitize user input. But I use Markdown which means I need the blockquote > symbol to go through without being escaped as & gt; so I can pass it to misaka for rendering.

The documentation says by default it escapes html markup but doesn't say how to turn that off for the > symbol. I would still like it to escape actual html tags.

http://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clean.html

Any other ideas for sanitizing input while maintaing the ability to use Markdown would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need strip all tags, but leave > as it is?

1. strip all tags, get output
2. html decode output of step 1, and pass that data to misaka

Simple way for step 2:

> output.replace('&gt;', '>')

More professional

```
import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
s = h.unescape(sanitized user input)
```

Comment: thanks! the simple way works fine as a quick solution but it does match all > symbols, including at the end of html tags. is it possible to get it to match just the > occuring after a new line? i wasn't able to do replace('\n&gt;','>')

Answer (score 2):

Bleach is a HTML sanitizer, not a Markdown sanitizer. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052233/cleaning-user-created-markdown-with-code-in-it/21058234#21058234), you should run your user input through Markdown first, then through Bleach. Like this:

```
sanitized_html = bleach.clean(markdown.markdown(some_text))
```

For more info, see my previously referenced [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052233/cleaning-user-created-markdown-with-code-in-it/21058234#21058234).

Comment: most people [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266650/should-i-sanitize-markdown) say you need to sanitize markdown before you save it in the database. like the OP in that thread, i have a field in the database for both the original markdown and the generated html.

Comment: @aris that is not how I read those comments. In fact, they state that you should sanitize "before sending to web clients". I don't see anyone specifically saying you should sanitize before saving to the DB (even though that was the OP's question). Either way, Bleach is not a Markdown sanitizer, so it is the wrong tool for the job.